# Cannot set custom font

Tags: android, xamarin, custom-controls

I am trying to give my own `EditText` class a typeface with

```
public class MyEditText : EditText
{
  public MyEditText(Context context) : base(context)
  {
      InitializeView(context);
  }

  public MyEditText (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
  {
      InitializeView(context);
  }

  public MyEditText (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context,attrs,defStyle)
  {
      InitializeView(context);
  }

  private void InitializeView(Context context)
  {
      this.Typeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Context.Assets, "Fonts/segoeui.ttf");
  }
}
```

But all I get is this error

> Error CS0176: Member
>   'Android.Graphics.Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Android.Content.Res.AssetManager,
>   string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it
>   with a type name instead

I already tried `Application.Context`, but it didn't help. 
Why is this happening?

Comment: That makes no difference.

Comment: Just keep in mind that creating font from asset is a big performance issue. I suggest you to use a singleton class to keep the created font in the memory to avoid opening the asset file every time your `EditText` appears in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is confusing the Typespace property of the class and the Typeface class in Android.Graphics

```
this.Typeface = Android.Graphics.Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Context.Assets, "Fonts/segoeui.ttf");
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to use `global::Android.Graphics.Typeface.CreateFromAsset` in my case.